# Are 2D materials really two dimensional?

Tags: material-science, spacetime-dimensions

I am learning more about 2D materials. Does anyone have any reference, literature, videos, lecuters for basics?

Main question for start is that why called 2d? Because even if it one layer of atom, it still has some thickness?

Comment: Indeed, it has a thickness, but the point is that the third dimension doesn’t add anything. The quantum energy levels that are nonuniform in the third dimension are too high in energy to matter.

Comment: @knzhou It's my understanding that comments are either to ask clarifying questions or suggest improvements to the question (which is what the comment box says before typing). I keep seeing you post answers as comments, but given your high number of reputation points it really confuses me as to what comments are really for.

Comment: @AaronStevens  I am also guilty of this, if the answer is trivial, or if my suggestions would take too long to make into a clear answer, I just comment. The last because I always try to find links for the answers , and that takes time.. Knzhou 's answer to be really an physics answer needs to go into description of materials and models etc to become a useful answer for future searches as reference.

Comment: @AaronStevens I believe in writing answers for the level of the OP. In this case it's clear that for my answer to have any value, it would have to explain quantum energy levels and how the energy levels depend on size, which is more than I was up for doing before bed. So I left a comment instead.

Comment: It's only an "answer" in the sense that it's logically complete, but by that standard every question ever asked on this site has a two-sentence "answer". I don't think it really counts.

Comment: @knzhou I used to do the same thing, but then on multiple occasions told not to to do it. I think a better solution would be to *If you have a partial answer - more than just a link, of course, but anything that actually does answer the question, no matter how short or lacking in detail - post it with a note that you'll come back and edit more detail in when you have time. (And of course, actually come back and edit more detail in when you have time.)* https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/964/answering-in-comments

Answer (score 0):

Many conceptual questions regarding 2D materials including the one posed here are addressed in the following document: [Ph.D. Thesis - Optical spectroscopy and hyloscopy of monolayers of tungsten disulphide](http://hdl.handle.net/1959.3/455711)

The main chapter to read is the Chapter 2: "Monolayers of TMDs".
All knowledge from this chapter is transferable to all 2D materials.

In a nutshell, they are referred to as "2D" because of the dimensionality of their respective Brillouin zone, and that along the Z-direction of the crystal structure electrons/excitons have only one quantum energy level. Therefore, all variations in the dynamics of quasi-particles ideally happen in the XY-plane of the material.